# Comparing substring in another string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two string I want to check if substring of one variable into another variable below is the code snippets.

```
var val1 = "www.google.com , www.yahoo.com , www.msn.com, in.news.yahoo.com";
    var val2 = "in.news.yahoo.com/huffington-post-removes-sonia-gandhi-rich-list-103404344.html";
//if val1 does not contains val2 I want to show popup. I tried val1 .toLowerCase().indexOf(val2 .toLowerCase()) but it doesn't work it always return -1.
```

can any one suggest me how can I put if condition?

Comment: That's because you are checking whether `val2` is a substring of `val1`, not any substring of `val2` is a substring of `val1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var val1 = "www.google.com,www.yahoo.com,www.msn.com,in.news.yahoo.com";
var val2 = "www.yahoo.com/huffington-post-removes-sonia-gandhi-rich-list-103404344.html";

function check(){
    var val1_arr = val1.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < val1_arr.length; i++){
       if(val2.indexOf(val1_arr[i]) != -1){
         // val2 contains val1
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would be better to remove the need for jQuery. Plus [].each won't work. It'll need to be `$.each(var1_arr, function(...`

Comment: Sorry, I have just checked this. Try it again!

Comment: In your code, if `val2` contains multiple instances of `val1`, you're going to get multiple popups.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
val1 = [ "www.google.com",
         "www.yahoo.com",
         "www.msn.com",
         "in.news.yahoo.com" ];

function showPopUpIfUrlIsInVal1(val2) {
    var b = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < val1.length; i++)
    {
        if (val2.indexOf(val1[i]) > -1)
        {
            b = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (b)
    {
         alert("test message");
    }
}

showPopUpIfUrlIsInVal1("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is a fun one, here's a FP way of solving this problem:

```
var val1 = "www.google.com , www.yahoo.com , www.msn.com,in.news.yahoo.com";
var val2 = "in.news.yahoo.com/huffington-post-removes-sonia-gandhi-rich-list-103404344.html";

function arrayInString(needles, haystack, callback) {
    var result = needles.some(function(el) {
        return haystack.indexOf(el.trim()); // Trim is required to remove extra whitespace
    });
    if (result) callback();
}

arrayInString(val1.split(","), val2, function() {
    // Create your popup here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8Sjc/)

```
   //fixing val1 format    
   var val1 = "www.google.com , www.yahoo.com , www.msn.com , in.news.yahoo.com";

    var matched = val1.split(' , ').filter(function (v) {
        return ~val2.indexOf(v);
    });
```